# Moving millions of files to a different directory with specfic name patterns

Tags: file-copy

I have millions of files with the following nomenclature on a Linux machine:

```
1559704165_a1ac6f55fef555ee.jpg
```

The first 10 digits are timestamp and the ones followed by a `_` are specific ids.  I want to move all the files matching specific filename ids to a different folder.

I tried this on the directory with files

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | ??????????_a1ac*.jpg |xargs mv -t "/home/ubuntu/ntest"
```

However I am getting an error indicating:

```
bash 1559704165_a1ac6f55fef555ee.jpg: command not found
```

When I tried, `mv ??????????_a1ac*.jpg`  I am getting argument list too long error.   I have atleast 15 different filename patterns.  How do I move them.

Comment: The bash says it all: it tries to *execute* that filename as it is the first on the line in the 2nd stage of the pipe (your 2nd stage pipe is:   `| ??????????_a1ac*.jpg`: bash expands it to several filename, the first being `1559704165_a1ac6f55fef555ee.jpg`, si you end up, in that 2nd pipe stage, trying to execute:  `1559704165_a1ac6f55fef555ee.jpg  next_matching_filename 3rd_matching_filename ... nth_matching_filename`. I guess you tried instead to *filter* to that filename (see answers below for that)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '??????????_a1ac*.jpg' \
-exec mv -t destination "{}" +
```

So `maxdepth 1` means that you want to search in current directory no subdirectories.

`type f` means find only files.

`name '??????????_a1ac*.jpg'` is a pattern that matches with file you are searching.

`mv -t destination "{}" +` means move matched files to destination. Here `+` adds new matched files to previous one like:

```
mv -t dest a b c d
```

Here a b c d are different files.

Comment: Thanks for concisely answering this persons question. Rather than simply dumping a solution, maybe you could explain how/what/why. Instead of being useful to one person, one time, it can be useful to everyone, all the time. Same question has been asked & answered countless times over the last 40-50 years. Problem is, it's never explained well. Teach a man to fish.. In the meantime: http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Multiple-Files.html#Multiple-Files and as is often the case Wikipedia's more useful than the official docs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Note that `-t` is a GNU extension and so may not be available on other types of UNIX derivatives.

Comment: When you say *"Double quotes prevents word splitting."* I presume you are referring to `"{}"`, in which case I want to point out that `{}` is not expanded by the shell and does not need to be quoted. The shell passes `{}` to find, and find sees `{}` and replaces it with pathnames. Find exec does not use the shell parser and does not do any word-splitting of its own. Quoting it does not do any harm, it is just that the justification given is a bit inaccurate.

Comment: @jw013 thanks .

Answer (score 11):

Your command,

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | ??????????_a1ac*.jpg |xargs mv -t "/home/ubuntu/ntest"
```

Pipes the list of all the files TO all the files!

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name `*_a1ac*.jpg` -print0 |\
xargs  -0 -r mv -t "/home/ubuntu/ntest"
```

will do the trick.

Comment: many thanks...your solution worked too...thank you for letting me know where I went wrong

Answer (score 8):

You're very close.  You should use the `-name` option to `find`.  And remember to quote the pattern.

So

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '??????????_a1ac*.jpg' |xargs mv -t "/home/ubuntu/ntest"
```

Comment: Many thanks...your solution worked too....additional thanks for letting me know i was close to the solution....its a motivator for a novice like me

Comment: you should add a `-print0` as the last argument to the find (instead of the default: -print), and add a `-0` as the first option to xargs  (ie: `xargs -0 mv -t "/home/ubuntu/ntest"` ). that way, all kind of weird filenames (with spaces in it, with "newline" in it, etc) can be handled. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '??????????_a1ac*.jpg' -print0 |xargs -0 mv -t "/home/ubuntu/ntest"`  (works only with GNU-like find, though)

Answer (score 2):

Not as "good" as the `find` solutions, but another valid solution is to make the `mv` commands more granular.

This does 4096 moves, with a fewer number of files moved per `mv` operation.

```
FILEPAT=a1ac
for i in $(seq $((0x000)) $((0xfff))); 
do 
   H=$(printf '%x\n' $i)
   mv 1559704165_${FILEPAT}${H}*.jpg /home/ubuntu/ntest
done
```

Comment: This is a clever hack for those without `find` (for whatever reason).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to move files on the same host system, which I guess you are doing with your `mv`, `rsync` could be a faster option:

```
rsync -av --inplace -W /source/??????????_a1ac*.jpg /home/ubuntu/ntest/
```

`--inplace`and `-W` are set to speed up the process.

Should this yield another *argument list too long error* then you could feed lists to `rsync`

Make the list with find, for example

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '??????????_a1ac*.jpg' > /tmp/my_image_list.txt
```

and give it to `rsync`

```
rsync -av --inplace -W --files-from=/tmp/my_image_list.txt /path/to/files /home/ubuntu/ntest/
```

The source here is `/path/to/files`, because `rsync` will treat the list you give it as relative to your source.

---

The point being: **`rsync` is faster than `mv`, if the files are not on the same filesystem**.

Comment: This is likely to hit the same "argument list too long" error the OP mentioned

Comment: @Grump, to avoid this, OP could write the list of files to copy to a file, i.e. `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '??????????_a1ac*.jpg' > /tmp/my_image_list.txt` and then pass it to rsync with `--files-from=/tmp/my_image_list.txt`. The point being that `rsync` is faster. Unless the files reside on the same filesystem, which OP has not indicated.

Comment: @RobertRiedl: you should edit your answer and add this information. Comments can be impermanent.

Comment: @NickD, I've updated my answer.

Comment: It's not true that `rsync` is faster unless you need to do incremental copies.

Comment: @forest if they are on the same filesystem, then `mv` is faster. If they are not, then `rsync` is faster (most of the time). Depends heavily on the environment. `rsync` can also do compression, etc  - OP never stated that the files will be moved inside the same filesystem. If bandwidth is not the issue, then you can even pipe `tar` trough `nc` which will blow `mv` right out of the water.